# Move item to section

Tags: swift

I can not understand what the problem is. By clicking on the cell, the item is marked as completed and moves to the appropriate section. But I noticed a bug, if after clicking on the item, click on it again, then it bugs (see gif below). First, I change the state of the item, then delete it from the common array, and then add it to the corresponding section.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let isCompleted: Bool
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        if isFiltering {
            let task = manager.filteredTasks[indexPath.row]
            task.isCompleted = !task.isCompleted
            isCompleted = task.isCompleted
        } else {
            isCompleted = manager.changeState(at: indexPath.section == 0 ? manager.toDoTasks[indexPath.row].id : manager.completedTasks[indexPath.row].id)
        }
        let lastTask: Task = manager.tasks[indexPath.row]
        manager.removeItem(with: lastTask.id)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            manager.addTask(task: lastTask)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: manager.completedTasks.count - 1, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
        } else {
            manager.addTask(task: lastTask)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: manager.toDoTasks.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        }
        let accessoryType: UITableViewCell.AccessoryType = isCompleted ? .checkmark : .none
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = accessoryType
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

 func changeState(at id: String) -> Bool {
        guard let task = tasks.first(where: { (item) -> Bool in
            item.id == id
        }) else { return false }
        task.isCompleted = !task.isCompleted
        computeSections()
        return task.isCompleted
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Keys.cell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ToDoCell
        print(indexPath)
        if isFiltering {
            cell.configureCell(task: manager.filteredTasks[indexPath.row])
        } else {
            cell.configureCell(task: indexPath.section == 0 ? manager.toDoTasks[indexPath.row] : manager.completedTasks[indexPath.row])
        }
        return cell
    }
```

[image: bug]

Comment: Not enough code to reproduce. I would like to see `cellForRow` and also what really happens inside manager when you are doing `changeState`.

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious right now. Are you sure `computeSections()` works correctly?

Comment: it's just filter tasks, i'm sure it's works correctly

Comment: Well, there is something suspicious. That `manager.removeItem` and `manager.addTask`. You are working with something called `manager.tasks[indexPath.row]` which is obviously neither `completedTasks` or `toDoTasks` but you are indexing that with `indexPath.row`.

Comment: this solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already observed in the comments

```
let lastTask: Task = manager.tasks[indexPath.row]
```

is suspicious and probably should be replaced with:

```
let lastTask = indexPath.section == 0
    ? manager.toDoTasks[indexPath.row]
    : manager.completedTasks[indexPath.row]
```